# How to change password from the database?

Tags: sql, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I would like to change password in database manually, for example, i want mary tan's password to be changed from 12345 to 54321 only without affect the rest of the staff's password. I try to fix this problem but I really don't know how.

Here is my database table:

[click image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBYFH.jpg)

This is my aspx.cs code:

```
public partial class ChangePassword : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection conn = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        string connectionString = null;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnChangePassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LeaveManagementCS"].ConnectionString;

            conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            string sql = "UPDATE Staff Set Password=@NewPwd";

            if (Session["Username"] != null)
            {
                sql += " WHERE UserName='" + Session["Username"].ToString() + "'";
            }

            string newPwd = tbNewPassword.Text;

            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewPwd", tbNewPassword.Text);

                conn.Open();


                int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (rows > 0)
                {
                    lblOutput.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    lblOutput.Text = "Password has been changed successfully";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblOutput.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    lblOutput.Text = "Password does not match with our database records.";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblOutput.Text = "Error Message: " + ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.Close();
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class ChangePassword : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection conn = null;
    SqlCommand cmd = null;
    string connectionString = null;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnChangePassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

if (Session["Username"] == null){return;} //Just add this line because you MUST have to make this check , otherwise all users password would get changed

        connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LeaveManagementCS"].ConnectionString;

        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        string sql = "UPDATE Staff Set Password=@NewPwd Where Username = @Username";

        string newPwd = tbNewPassword.Text;

        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewPwd", tbNewPassword.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Session["Username"].ToString());
            conn.Open();


            int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (rows > 0)
            {
                lblOutput.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                lblOutput.Text = "Password has been changed successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                lblOutput.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                lblOutput.Text = "Password does not match with our database records.";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblOutput.Text = "Error Message: " + ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT run with that. If the `UserName` property isn't set in the Session object, it will set EVERYONE'S password to that value. You should not allow this to happen under any circumstance.

```
public partial class ChangePassword : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection conn = null;
    SqlCommand cmd = null;
    string connectionString = null;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnChangePassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LeaveManagementCS"].ConnectionString;

        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        string username = Session["Username"];
        string newPwd = tbNewPassword.Text;

        if (username != null)
        {
            string sql = "UPDATE Staff Set Password=@NewPwd WHERE UserName=@UserName";

            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewPwd", newPwd);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", username);

                conn.Open();

                int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (rows > 0)
                {
                    lblOutput.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    lblOutput.Text = "Password has been changed successfully";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblOutput.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    lblOutput.Text = "Password does not match with our database records.";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblOutput.Text = "Error Message: " + ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.Close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Even more appropriate, I would write a stored procedure that takes two parameters (ideally, the UserID and NewPassword, not the UserName and NewPassword) and call that in your code.